# How much water must I dump on the Sun to put it out forever?

Tags: water, mathematics, sun

Water blows out fire and stop it from burning. How much volume of water, $H_2O$, is needed to put out the sun forever?

Comment: Welcome Xandi99. The sun isn't on fire, it's a fusion reactor. Adding more hydrogen will not put it out, but add more fuel. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. We're a site for writers, game-designers and artists who are creating fictional worlds (and those who do it just for fun). There doesn't seem to be a worldbuilding question here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can find a short explanation of why this can't work at [XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/14/)

Comment: So, this is an interesting scenario --- but not really well written, as you can tell by the fact that your question was closed and is receiving unhelpful comments. In order to get this reopened, we'd need to have this rewritten so that it focuses on the worldbuilding problem of extinguishing a star with water. Please reformulate your question so that it focuses on the fictional world and its properties!

Comment: To further expand on Escaped Dental patient (mind the caries!) : A worldbuilding question denotes from pure physics by adding some surrounding context to it, some constraints. Here, can we know which civilization had this idea, and why? How is the water added to the sun : Massive ship import, teleportation...? It looks like some useless fluff, but it proves you're **building** something, and it could even change the answers!

Comment: To quote the XKCD comic John mentioned: *"Water is made of **Hydrogen** and Oxygen, which is **fuel** for the Sun’s fusion. But more importantly, the extra mass also makes the Sun **heavier**. This crushes it together more tightly and makes fusion happen **faster**. This means it will burn **more** brightly"* - Also, it's possible fuel a fusion reactor with Oxygen too, but you need ***MUCH*** higher temperatures/pressures than we've got in ***our*** sun... ***TLDR;*** *Adding water makes the sun **hotter!*** ... astrophysics is weird

Answer (score 6):

To collapse directly into a black hole and thereby "put out" the fusion reaction that powers the sun, you need about 20 times the mass of the Sun, or about 19 more Sun-Masses worth of water. Obviously that cannot all exist in the same space, or it would collapse on its own. So it must be delivered over time.

But then, yes, it would collapse directly into a black hole without any explosion, and "put out" the sun.

Understand the Sun isn't "burning" ***anything,*** the gravity-driven fusion reaction in its center is producing heat and helium. There is no "ash" or any "fuel" being **burned.** There also is not any **oxygen** involved -- water puts out fires by depriving them of oxygen which is used in the "burning" reaction. That is not what is happening in the Sun.

Finally, whether you dump water, asteroids, planets or other stars into the sun does not matter, if you can get the total mass up to 20x the current solar mass, it will collapse into a black hole.

Comment: Wouldn't you get a type I supernova at some point?  For the reason you cited, you can't dump all that mass into the star all at once, so the flow of matter would presumably push our little yellow dwarf past the Chandrasekhar limit.

Answer (score 0):

## Freaking Lots of Water.

The Sun puts out about $10^{26}$ Joules of energy per second. If we want to cancel that by heating water without the water evaporating we can absorb $4,184$ Joules with a kilo of water. That's about $10^3$ Joules per kilo. So we need $10^{23}$ kg of water.

**Daron, is that a lot?**

Well a sphere of water with radius $R$ contains about $R^3$ kilos of water. So we need a sphere of radius $10^{23/3} \simeq 10^8$ metres. That's about the same radius as the Sun.

So to put out the Sun you need a second Sun made of water, and you need to drop the water Sun on the fire Sun, without the water Sun collapsing under its own gravity to form a second Sun.

But wait, that's just to absorb the heat generated from one second. It won't switch the Sun off. One second later, the Sun will put out the same energy again, and we'll need a second water Sun. To put Mr Sun out for good, we need enough water to bring the Sun down from 5000 Kelvin to some smaller number where fusion cannot occur. So start with the 100000000 metre radius and add a few more zeroes.

The exact number  is in principle easy to compute, but I do not know the specific heat capacity of hydrogen at the temperature and pressure inside Earth's Sun. Xandi99, that is your homework to find out.

Comment: Much more indeed, the sun doesn’t undergo fusion because its hot, it just makes it easier. The sun’s fusion happens because quantum tunneling lets mass fuse, which is much more likely in the densely packed interior of a sun than on a regular old planet. The heat, assuming you can cool the interior off that easily, just adds to the amount of fusion reactions, this is counteracted by the extra mass pushing everything together and the lower of fusion reactions causing more pressure and heat. I doubt any amount of water is enough to put the flames of a sun out. You might cool the surface a moment.

Comment: @Demigan I imagine pointing your garden hose at the sky and blasting off a few hundred thousand Sunsworth will do something to slow down the fusion for some 10. . . 0s of years.

Comment: Ummm, no, that's not how it works, like, at all. Adding mass to the Sun won't stop the fusion reaction, on the contrary, it will add more fuel making the Sun last longer. The only possible effect is to diminish the output energy for a little while, but you can do that infinitely easier with a parasol.

Comment: @Daron (un?)fortunately not. The water will add pressure to the interior of the sun where the fusion happens. Even if you manage to freeze the outer shell with icewater the interior will simply get hotter from pressure. We don’t expect the earth interior to become cooler based on the weather above. That ignores the speed with which the water will approach at minumum, speed which will be turned into heat energy on approach.

Comment: Also, at the temperatures at the sun's surface, approaching water will be disassociated into oxygen and hydrogen... ie. more fuel.

Comment: @AlexP A little while on the astronomical scale might be a very long while for you and me.

Comment: @Demigan The weather is much smaller than the planet itself.

Comment: @AlexP Adding mass adds more fuel but also accelerates the fusion (because more mass = more gravity). That's why large stars die sooner but burn brighter. You reduce mass to extend life, to a point.